# VI editor - saving filename in :wq

Tags: linux, unix, centos, redhat, vi

After typing whatever that I need in **VI**, i wanted to save it to a file with `:wq` filename.  But if I have type in the wrong filename , there is no way for me to amend it.

Moving the cursor to yth character and typing x will replace the wrong `character(yth)` with `x`
Pressing `backspace` or delete will just move the cursor left instead of removing the wrong character
Pressing `esc` or back arrow will save the file

How do I change delete a wrong word/character in `:wq` wrongfilename ?

e.g: `wq wrongfilename` -- I want to remove `filename` , how do I do that?

Comment: When you press backspace and the cursor moves left, you still  see the characters. I think you can just give enter or type the new characters. Are the characters right of the cursor still part of your command or only a 'shadow' of the precious input?

Comment: If the terminal is set correctly, you should be able to use normal editing keys, and ESC should abort the command.

Answer (score 3):

Enter **:wq** followed by **file name** to save the file

**Eg:**

> :wq filename.txt

Answer (score 1):

Use shift key while pressing back arrow. This does the trick for me